# Solving numerically a linear ODE

Tags: differential-equations, na.numerical-analysis

I start by saying that I do not have a strong background in numerical analysis, so I may miss some basic things or make trivial mistakes.

Motivated by some problems in digital signal processing, I would like to solve numerically a linear ODE of order $m$ of the form:
\begin{equation*}
y(t)+ a_1(t) y'(t) + \dots + a_m(t) y^{(m)}(t) = b_0(t) x(t) + b_1(t) x'(t) + \dots + b_m(t) x^{(m)}(t),
\end{equation*}
where $x$ is known (input) and $y$ is unknown (output). Let $f_s > 0$ be the sampling rate and $y[n] = y(n/f_s)$ the approximate solution we want. We can also put:
\begin{equation*}
f(t) := b_0(t) x(t) + \dots + b_m(t) x^{(m)}(t).
\end{equation*}

This is what I have done so far. First of all, I reduced the equation to a linear first-order differential system in the usual way:
\begin{equation*}
\begin{cases}
y_0(t) + a_1(t) y_1(t) + \dots + a_m(t) y_m(t) = f(t) \\
y'_0 (t) = y_1(t) \\
\dots \\
y'_{m-1}(t) = y_m(t). \\
\end{cases}
\end{equation*}
Then I used the following linear 1-step method:
\begin{equation} \label{eq:method}
y'[n] \simeq (\alpha+1) f_s \ y[n] - (\alpha+1) f_s \ y[n-1] - \alpha \ y'[n-1],
\end{equation}
where $\alpha \in [0,1]$. So I got the following linear system
\begin{cases}
y_0[n] + a_1[n] y_1[n] + \dots + a_m[n] y_m[n] = f[n] \\
y_{i+1}[n] = (\alpha+1) f_s \ y_i[n] - (\alpha+1) f_s \ y_i[n-1] - \alpha \ y_{i+1}[n-1], \ i = 0, \dots, m-1 \\
\end{cases}
and the solution is recursively given by:
\begin{cases}
y_0[n] = \dfrac{f[n] + \sum_{i=1}^m \{ a_i[n] \sum_{j=1}^i (\alpha+1)^{i-j} f_s^{i-j}((\alpha+1) f_s \ y_i[n-1] + \alpha \ y_{i+1}[n-1])\}}{1 + \sum_{i=1}^m a_i[n] (\alpha+1)^i f_s^i} \\
y_{i+1}[n] = (\alpha+1) f_s \ y_i[n] - (\alpha+1) f_s \ y_i[n-1] - \alpha \ y_{i+1}[n-1], \ i = 0, \dots, m-1  \end{cases}

Here are my questions.

1) Did I do anything wrong?

2) Does the reduction from one $m$-th order equation to a system of $1$-st order equations affect the quality of the solution? Is there any alternative? For example, how do you compare it to multistep methods?

3) The most general linear 1-step method is given by:
\begin{equation*}
y'[n] \simeq k_1 y[n] + k_2 y[n-1] + k_3 y'[n-1],
\end{equation*}
where $k_1, k_2, k_3 \in \mathbb R$. The previous expression in terms of $\alpha$ and $f_s$ is obtained asking the method to be $1$-st order at least, while the additional condition $\alpha \in [0,1]$ is used to avoid stability issues. Notice that for $\alpha = 0$ you get backward Euler, for $\alpha = 1$ the trapezoidal rule and for $\alpha \to \infty$ forward Euler. I found this class of methods in previous papers (e.g. Germain, François G., and Kurt J. Werner. "Design principles for lumped model discretisation using Möbius transforms." Proc. DAFx-15, 2015), but I can not find more information. Do you know any reference on that? Can you compare it, in terms of efficiency and accuracy, with more usual (classes of) methods?

4) In general, could you provide me references for numerical methods for ODEs, particularly linear?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I suggest you to head over to [scicomp.se]; this is not off-topic here, but you will find a larger number of people working in numerics among the regulars there.

Comment: @FedericoPoloni thank you very much.

Comment: Hi Avril, I suggest you look at the books by Hairer, Wanner, and Norsett "Solving Ordinary differential equations". Converting higher order initial value problems (IVPs) to first order systems is rather standard (there are exceptions, of course). To solve IVPs you can use Runge-Kutta methods or linear multi-step methods (a lot of choice there).